# Why is Firebug's console.trace reporting 'anonymous' as the function name during the trace?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Say I have the following code:

```
var f1 = function (a) {
    return f2(a + 1);
};
var f2 = function (a) {
    return f3(a + 1);
}
var f3 = function (a) {
    console.trace();
};

f1(5);
```

I am doing a `console.trace` in `f3` and this is what the Console is displaying:

[image: Firebug trace]

---

My question is, why is Firebug displaying `anonymous` instead of the function names during the trace?

Comment: Those don't have function names. Those are anonymous functions, which you happen to be assigning to variable names. You could have multiple variables pointing to the same anonymous function, what would Firebug do then?

Comment: Oh now I understand.  Infact, if instead of creating a function and assigning it to a variable, I use `function f1 () {` it works!

Comment: @Eric Muyser: you probably should have submitted that as an answer. You were clearly the fastest to write the answer but he can't accept a comment as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite it like this to name your functions instead of using anonymous functions:

```
function f1(a) {
    return f2(a + 1);
};
function f2(a) {
    return f3(a + 1);
}
function f3(a) {
    console.trace();
};

f1(5);
```

See [this page](http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/) for a good description of the differences between the two syntaxes.

Answer (score 2):

```
function f1(a) {
    return f2(a + 1);
};
function f2(a) {
    return f3(a + 1);
}
function f3(a) {
    console.trace();
};

f1(5);
```

Would display the function names. Se [here](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are anonymous functions. For the JavaScript Interpreter `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are just variable names. Consider the following code:

```
var foo = function(a) {
    return f2(a + 1);
};
var f1 = foo;
foo = "bar"
```

The intepreter and thus FireBug cannot know, whether the function name is `foo`, `f1` or something completely differnt. For the interpreter it is just an anonymous function. You can rewrite your code using named functions like this:

```
function f1(a) {
    return f2(a + 1);
};
```

You can even assign the named function to a variable:

```
var f1 = function f1(a) {
    return f2(a + 1);
};
```

In this case the function name will always be `f1` regardless of the variable's name.

Newer builds of the WebKit and Chrome Inspector support the `displayName` property on functions [1](http://www.alertdebugging.com/2009/04/29/building-a-better-javascript-profiler-with-webkit/). If an anonymous function has such a property, the value of the property is used as the function name. In your code you could e.g. write:

```
var f1 = function(a) {
    return f2(a + 1);
};
f.displayName = "f1".
```